# searchBarSearchButtonClicked not working

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have set the delegate in the viewDidLoad() method and also checked the IB to see if the delegate shows up when using (control + drag) and it does infact show as being hooked up. I deleted it as well and added a new SearchBar entirely in IB and hooked it back up. Nothing seems to do the trick. Any suggestions?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.searchBar.layer.zPosition = 1
    self.searchBar.delegate = self
}

//this is never being called, breakpoint never hits
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("searchText \(searchText)")
}

//this is never being called, breakpoint never hits
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("search button clicked")
    self.firebaseQuery()
}
```

Comment: Try in this way: extension yourViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(" keyboard search button was tapped: \(searchBar).")
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }}

Comment: @Sidharth Sharma, I just tried your code and it works fine for me. I do not see any issues.

Comment: some how it is still not working for me @Shivakumar

Answer (score 1):

Is your custom View Controller class set in Interface Builder? I.e. on the Identity Inspector tab, ensure your desired UIViewController subclass is set in the Custom Class section.

Also, try setting a breakpoint in viewDidLoad(). Run the app and if the breakpoint doesn't get hit when you expect, that helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: yep it is set in the Identity Inspector already. I am hitting the viewDidLoad method but not the other delegate methods of UISearchBar

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/85o75h/bug_uisearchbar_delegate_methods_not_being_called/dvzcbb4/

Thanks to reddit user @applishish I got the issue

I did not put a underscore in front of the parameter -_-

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're setting the delegate incorrectly?

In Interface Builder, command-click the search bar, drag the delegate to the yellow ViewController button in the storyboard to set the delegate.
Remove `self.searchBar.delegate = self` from `viewDidLoad()`

[image: Set ViewController as UISearchBarDelegate Xcode 9.4 beta]

I'm also not seeing if your viewController Class has properly conformed to `UISearchBarDelegate` I would add it in an extension to your controller and put all your code relating to it there.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController{...}


 extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
     // implement all searchBar related methods here: 

    func searchBarButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       //capture the string 
       if let input = searchBar.text {
        // do something with string.  
        print(input)


       }


 }
```

Comment: It's showing up correctly unfortunately. Removed the delegate call in viewDidLoad as well and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with it not responding when I set it up using IB. I finally set it up using code instead of IB, and it worked. Try it this way:

```
    class MySearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.none
        self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController

        //if this is set to true, the search bar hides when you scroll.
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

        //this is so I'm told of changes to what's typed
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
}

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {            
        //hopefully this gets called when you click Search button
}

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //if you want to start searching on each keystroke, you implement this method. I'm going to wait until they click Search.
    }
```

Comment: I think they're interrelated. The user just sees the UISearchBar, but the UISearchController is what controls all the searching behind the scenes. My VC looks just like yours--a UISearchBar at the top, the user types a word, hits enter, and searchBarSearchButtonClicked is called. I'm definitely no expert with it, but I followed this tutorial and got it working: [https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started] (https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: this seems like it's updating the table view with results as it goes rather than allowing a user to submit a query though correct?

Comment: That's only if you want to. In my case, when `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` is called, I retrieve the string they typed using the `self.searchController.searchBar.text` property. That's the only thing the controller does for me. From that point, I split the string on spaces so I know the keywords they searched for, and I do stuff with that string. The controller doesn't do anything additional.